# centos out of memory

Tags: centos, memory

I rent a CentOS service, and with no permission creat a `swap`, now I now I am slow open my site, slow access with `putty`. When I tried many times, finally see my `root` part with `putty`

Here is a list of system situation by `top` commond, I am not sure why my centos system caused `out of memory`? (2G memory used) And how to avoid `out of memory`?Any good way to release memory when it nearly out of? Thanks.

```
Tasks: 390 total,   1 running, 389 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 11.8%us,  2.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 85.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   2097152k total,  2097152k used,        0k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,        0k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
18362 mysql     15   0  774m 307m 6532 S 99.8 15.0  177:06 mysqld
20047 root      18   0 29780  12m 6256 S  4.3  0.6   0:00.42 php
17644 root      18   0 33380  16m 6412 S  3.0  0.8   0:04.25 php
20168 root      16   0 31896  15m 6360 S  2.3  0.7   0:02.30 php
18219 root      18   0 32376  15m 6400 S  1.7  0.8   0:02.68 php
18394 root      18   0 32116  15m 6408 S  1.0  0.8   0:02.35 php
20097 root      15   0 33020  16m 6360 S  1.0  0.8   0:03.05 php
20159 root      15   0  2504 1244  812 R  0.7  0.1   0:00.48 top
17972 root      15   0 33368  16m 6404 S  0.3  0.8   0:02.46 php
19492 root      15   0 31860  15m 6408 S  0.3  0.7   0:01.92 php
    1 root      18   0  2156  664  576 S  0.0  0.0   0:26.77 init
 1215 root      15  -4  2260  652  436 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 udevd
 1303 root      22   0  3880 1424  796 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 crond
 1305 root      15   0 30780  13m 6116 S  0.0  0.7   0:10.62 php
 1573 root      25   0  3880 1424  796 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 crond
 1574 root      18   0 32152  15m 6360 S  0.0  0.7   0:11.36 php
 1585 root      25   0  2832  868  700 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xinetd
```

**EDIT:**

`stoped mysqld`, sort `RES` from top

```
20190 root      18   0 38256 6400 S  21m  0.0  1.0   0:04.74 php
20189 root      15   0 37004 6408 S  20m  0.0  1.0   0:04.17 php
19827 root      15   0 36212 6400 S  19m  0.0  1.0   0:06.29 php
20047 root      15   0 35412 6408 S  18m  0.0  0.9   0:03.09 php
20211 root      15   0 34968 6408 S  18m  0.0  0.9   0:01.53 php
20213 root      18   0 34684 6724 S  18m  0.0  0.9   0:25.12 php
16258 root      18   0 33636 6408 S  17m  0.0  0.8   0:06.29 php
20177 root      18   0 33380 6408 S  16m  0.0  0.8   0:03.93 php
21969 root      18   0 33348 6400 S  16m  0.0  0.8   0:01.27 php
21813 root      18   0 33152 6408 S  16m  0.0  0.8   0:02.50 php
20227 root      15   0 33152 6404 S  16m  0.0  0.8   0:03.39 php
21876 root      18   0 33004 6404 S  16m  0.0  0.8   0:01.22 php
21747 root      15   0 32596 6732 S  16m  0.0  0.8   0:19.16 php
21762 root      15   0 32872 6404 S  16m  0.0  0.8   0:02.05 php
 7821 root      18   0 32920 6360 S  16m  0.0  0.8   0:03.27 php
13783 root      18   0 32920 6360 S  16m  0.0  0.8   0:03.37 php
20066 root      18   0 32984 6360 S  16m  0.0  0.8   0:02.66 php
15511 root      18   0 32916 6356 S  16m  0.0  0.8   0:09.72 php
21771 root      18   0 32912 6400 S  16m  0.0  0.8   0:02.45 php
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
Tasks: 217 total,   1 running, 216 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.2%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   2097152k total,   983132k used,  1114020k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,        0k cached
```

Comment: Use top to sort by memory usage (RES). Please provide another "screenshot" while the system still has got RAM available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like mySQL ate up your memory. Lower the memory amount that mysql is allowed to use. The configuration file should be found at **/etc/my.cnf**.

Comment: now, my system is slow to open `my.cnf.` how to release memory first? I have tried `httpd, mysqld restart`, thanks.

Comment: If you can afford a downtime, `service mysqld stop`.

Comment: SORRY for a long time, memory still used 2GB. I tried many times for access `putty` without timeout. then stop mysqld, `sort by RES`, see my `EDIT`, it seems many `php script` died.

Comment: Ok - no other memory hogs are visible. Now edit the my.cnf so mysql eats less memory. Look at the [online-documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-use.html) if you do not have an appropriate admin-tool for mysql at hand.

Comment: the mysqld still stoped, now I find I have released `1114020k memory` and `CPU` usage neally `zero`, but my service still slowly as before. where is the problem? cry :(

Comment: ok, i'll reboot it, then see what it else after 10 minutes, thanks.

Comment: So you don`t need mysql? I am a little bit confused. Why your system is still slow: There is only one CPU to handle over 180 php-processes (BTW - why are there so many of them?), so the CPU is probably busy doing process-switches.