# centos how to free memory with crontab

Tags: centos, memory

My system is Centos 5.5 with 2G memory, I have no permission setup a swap. I have set restart `mysqld, httpd` in 3:00 every day with `crontab`, and I also want to free memory every hour.

So how to free memory with crontab? I write some code below styding from web, but it seems not work...

> > crontab -e

```
6 * * * * sync;echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

**EDIT** here is `my.cnf`, however I need `fulltext` search sometimes used `oderby date`.

```
key_buffer_size = 256M
max_allowed_packet = 8M
max_connections=1024
wait_timeout=5
table_open_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 256M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_limit=2M
query_cache_size= 128M
thread_concurrency = 8
read_rnd_buffer_size=2M
tmp_table_size=128M
ft_min_word_len=2
ft_max_word_len=42
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?  What benefit do you believe you are getting?  It sure seems like are making your system run worse.

Comment: @Zoredache, yesterday, I find my system out of memory, see http://serverfault.com/questions/365029/centos-out-of-memory, the system slowly and hard to do anything, even restart mysqld,httpd, finnally I reboot my server. So i am trying to find someway to free memory automaticlly. thanks.

Comment: Restarting services or the server is the wrong solution.  Adjust the mysql configuration so that it won't go over certain limits.  You could also setup something like monit so that it only acts when there is actually a problem.

Comment: @Zoredache, I have update `my.cnf`, is it set reasonable? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you cited will cause the kernel to discard any cached data it has ... which is exactly the memory that it would have discarded as soon as anything wanted to use more memory anyhow.  It will have no practical effect on your system.

Ultimately, other than running less software, or restarting processes, there is nothing you can do to reclaim extra memory.  Linux has no mechanism to signal memory pressure to an application before killing it as "out of memory".

Comment: yesterday, I find my system `out of memory`, the server become slowlly, it is hard to access SSH via putty because always timeout, so I am try to find some way to avoid `out of memory`.

Comment: The approach you have cited above will absolutely, without doubt, not solve your problem.  The only way to solve your problem is to run less software, or to make the software you run consume less memory.  That requires specific configuration of the software in question, and cannot possibly be done in a generic way on that platform.

Comment: the most problem maybe mysql, I have update `my.cnf` setting. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to Free memory is to first know that what is eating up your EXTRA memory.
To find it out, you can use command 'htop', which will tell you that which process is eating up how much amount of memory.

and check the memory with 'free -m' .

Then you have to ONLY restart that process or evaluate that why it is taking large amount of memory.

Comment: I find mysqld occupied 740MB, others, many php script, each cost 5-18MB... and if user online rising, the system will out of memory, and the server become slow...

Comment: Then i would recommend that you must carefully evaluate your application's memory requirements, may be it is taking much more memory. Otherwise you Must add more memory (And Swap as well), otherwise the server might crash as well, if it can out of memory.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a reasonable high hit rate on your server, why not consider adding more RAM? This should solve the issue after tuning mysql/httpd parameters to make sure it did not eat your memory again.